# how to know a position of integer in another integer

Tags: java

Is there a way to find if an integer occurs in another integer? For example if two integers A and B are given. Integer A occurs in Integer B at position P then the leftmost position should be returned.

For example, 53 occurs in 1953786 at position 2, so the function should return 2.

Comment: create a String from both, and use substring

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        int n1 = 53;
        int n2 = 1953786;
        System.out.println(getIndexOfAinB(n1,n2));
}
private static int getIndexOfAinB(int n1, int n2) {
        String str1 = Integer.toString(n1);
        String str2  = Integer.toString(n2);
        return str2.indexOf(str1);
}
```

Comment: This only gives the first occurrence

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by first converting the two integers into strings, like so:

```
String stringA = a + "";  // a is an integer
String stringB = b + "";  // b is also an integer
```

Then, you can use the method `indexOf` in the String class to find the index. However, if the string is not found, the value `-1` is returned:

```
int index = stringA.indexOf(stringB);
if (index > -1)  // the string is found
    System.out.println("The occurrence is at " + index);
else  // the string is NOT found
    System.out.println("The string is not found.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String::indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) on strings created from the `int`s using [`Integer::toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int)):

```java
int i1 = 53;
int i2 = 1953786;

int pos = Integer.toString(i2).indexOf(Integer.toString(i1));
//  ^
//  `- 2
```